# Reason for three phases in total fatty matter test on soap

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, soap

I am currently trying to perform the Total Fatty Matter (TFM) test on soap and for some reason I am getting three phases instead of two.

The surfactant used is SLES and other reagents include hot water, $\ce{HCl}$, petroleum ether.

I have no idea as to what could be causing the 3 phases and my knowledge in organic chemistry is very little. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the procedure:

I dissolve soap in hot water and then I transfer the cooled solution to a decantation flask. I add concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ (37% stock solution) and then petroleum ether to increase extraction ratio.

I repeat this extraction two more times (and after this I am getting 3 phases) and then I purify the organic phase twice using hot water to eliminate any $\ce{HCl}$.

I then heat the organic phase to vaporize ether and calculate TFM %.

The surfactant used in the soap is sodium laureth sulfate (SLES), and I think that it may relate to why I have 3 phases but I can't tell why. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @Waylander See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151943/three-phases-in-tfm-test-instead-of-two